# Javascript Browser Plugin IsEnabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am doing some stuff with Google Earth and want to know if the Browser Plugin for Google Earth is Enabled or not (Note: Situations Like **the Plugin is Installed but disabled**)

How I plan to do this.
1. Detect if the Plugin is Installed
       Done using `google.earth.isSupported();`
2. Detect if the Plugin is enabled (**This is where the Problem is**)

Would like to know if there is something to Detect if the Plugin is Installed but Disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin is not available in either case. It is not possible to check if it's installed but disabled. The browser doesn't expose disabled plugins to scripts at all.

Comment: Is It Possible to Check the same from Server end by any chance. Using ASP.net technology.

Comment: Obviously not. How would the server know it if the client doesn't?